# When I scroll the list, the tab bar "vibrate"

Tags: flutter

I have a TabBar in the AppBar and a ListView in the TabBarView. When I scroll the list, the TabBar "vibrate". If you notice at the gif below, there actually appears a little white space at the bottom of AppBar, below the tabs. This space appears and disappears so fast that it gives an impression of vibration. I want the TabBar to be at the bottom of the AppBar with no space below the TabBar.

The code of AppBar:

```
_appBar(){
    return PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(160),
      child: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shadowColor: Colors.black,
        elevation: 7,
        centerTitle: true,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(90.0),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(243, 243, 243, 1),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Form(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: searchController,
                        autocorrect: false,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 1, left: 14, top: 14, bottom: 14),
                          label: Text("Nome, nº de série"),
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(60, 60, 67, 0.6)
                          ),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                TabBar(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
                    indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                    indicatorWeight: 3.0,
                    labelColor: Colors.black,
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontFamily: "OpenSans"
                    ),
                    tabs: const [
                      Tab(text: "RASCUNHOS"),
                      Tab(text: "EM PROCESSO"),
                      Tab(text: "FINALIZADO"),
                    ]
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I already removed the TabBar indicator decorations and the problem still happens.

[image]